# Using SQL Server with Access Forms or ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, ms-access, ms-access-2007

What would be the pros and cons of taking a large (16000 LOC) existing Access 2007/Forms application and porting it to SQL Server 2005, while keeping the Access forms on the front end, versus porting the front end to a .NET technology, say ASP.NET 4.0 or MVC3?  The backend is definitely getting ported to SQL Server, with large schema modifications, so this question is about whether to use the existing Access Forms front end or not.  I don't take throwing away existing working code lightly!  On the other hand, the schema will be changing a lot.

If you had a lot of experience with ASP.NET/Oracle  but not with Access or SQL Server, how might this change your answer?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: This statement may be a bit of a mis-direction: "I don't take throwing away existing working code lightly!"  Most likely your "major schema overhaul" would force extensive changes to the existing Access front-end.  So more accurately the choices you're considering are major revision to Access front-end vs. using Dot Net for the front-end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with Access as a front-end to an RDBMS whether SQL Server or another

Porting the front-end but leaving an Access back-end would seem a bit weird: why bother? Access is a good presentation tool but mediocre DBMS. Why keep the mediocre?

Also, only change one component at once no matter what you do: data, then front end. Don't do a big bang approach and change the lot

Comment: We would definitely use SQL Server as the back end no matter what, I edited the question to make that more clear.  I am a C# guy, but I don't want to let that sway me from staying with a VB/Access/Forms solution if it makes the most sense.

Comment: @Mike: my answer still holds, I'll add more though

Comment: Please do if you could give some specifics that I could use as concrete justifications. :)

Comment: The schema is going to be revised dramatically, which would cause a lot of code changes anyway.  At some point it must make sense to migrate away from Access.  But I have no feel whatsoever for where that point lies.  Basically I have no idea how friendly or how testable Access apps are.

Comment: Why not hide the schema changes behind views so Access sees the same?For writes, use INSTEAD OF triggers to capture them

Comment: That could help.  We are going for a major schema overhaul and simplification, which is the main point of the port, so I wouldn't want to do too much of that.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily "make sense to migrate away from Access" -- it entirely depends on the deployment environment.

Comment: The requirement to do this has gone away, but I really should give one of the people who answered credit, to say thank you, and to stop StackOverflow from pestering me about it.  And I had to pick one of you.  Thanks to all who answered or commented.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, comparing going with web application (ASP.NET) and stand-alone (Access) is not truly "apples-to-apples" comparison. It highly depends on your requirements.

Sure, going with web application will require much more developer's efforts comparing to building forms/reports in Access. But, the pay-off will be felt in the mid to long term.

You should also consider scalability, deployment, and availability issues when deciding to go/stay with Access.